# PHP mail() is not accepting variables

Tags: php, email

For some reason the $name, $email and $message variables aren't being passed into the $msgcontents and $headers variables. After I fill out the form and click submit the message in my inbox looks like this:

Subject:    Message from Contact Form

From:   Unknown sender

Date:   Mon, November 17, 2014 7:44 pm

To:     myemail@myemail.com

Name:
Email:
Message:

I've used var_dump() to see if my variables are being populated after clicking submit and they are but for some reason they are not being picked up by $msgcontents and $headers. Where am I going wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<?php

        $name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES));
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $message = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES));

            $to = "myemail@myemail.com";
            $subject = "Message From Contact Form";
            $msgcontents = "Name: $name <br>  Email: $email <br>  Message: $message";
            $headers = array("MIME-VERSION: 1.0",
                             "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1",
                              "From: $name <$email>",
                              "Reply-To: contact@info84.com",
                              "X-Mailer: PHP/" . PHP_VERSION
                             );
            $headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);      
            $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $msgcontents, $headers);                  
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form id="contactform" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" novalidate> 

    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Your Email">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submitform" value="send">
    </form>

<?php
var_dump($to); 
?>
<br>
<?php
var_dump($subject);
?> 
<br>
<?php
var_dump($msgcontents); 
?>
<br>
<?php
var_dump($headers); 
?>
<br>
<?php
var_dump($name); 
?>
<br>
<?php
var_dump($email); 
?>
<br>
<?php
var_dump($message); 
?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you show us form action rendered value?

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to php and coding. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: This about your `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"`. Can you to see, how it rendered in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think you check the message sended from first page load (without the form)

Try to wrap your email sending code, like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitform'])) {
  //...
  mail(...);
  //...
}
```

Then, when page loads no message been sended, but when you click a submit button, mail been sended